# Download a file with Chosen.js drop down

Tags: jquery

I am using chosen.js for a dropdown, (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) where I'd like to download a file based on the item clicked. Below is what my code looks like at the moment. It's the same as what they have in their example. I've been searching around & working this for a couple hours with no luck. Any thoughts?

```
  <form>
  <div id="container">
        <select data-placeholder="Choose a Location..."  class="chzn-select" style="width:550px;" tabindex="2">
          <option value=""></option> 
          <option value="http://example.com/folder/1100.pdf">1100</option>
          <option value="http://example.com/folder/0002.pdf">0002</option>
          <option value="http://example.com/folder/0011.pdf">0011</option>
          <option value="http://example.com/folder/0018.pdf">0018</option>
          <option value="http://example.com/folder/0021.pdf">0021</option>              
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> $(".chzn-select").chosen(); $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});</script>
  <script>

  </script>  
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're talking about, but here's what I'd try:

```
$('select.chzn-select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).find(':selected').length) {
    window.location = $(this).find(':selected').val();
  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is it possible to force it straight to download, versus opening in the browser, or is that a user setting that can't be over ridden?

Comment: That would have to happen through your server, IIRC. The browser usually handles downloads. You'd have to send the file with a `Content-Type` of something like raw data.